Why do you need to update the PATH variable for Python in Windows 11?
I have installed Python, but I don't remember what I did with the option (at install time) that relates to updating the PATH. Everywhere it says I have to update this. I have gone into system settings, and found the environment variables.
The "User variables" section has a PATH like this:

C:\Users\MYNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python313\Scripts\;etc etc

The "System variables" section has a PATH that includes this:
C:\windows\system32
In the second one, there is NO Python entry.
Am I doing it right, and what difference does all this make? [edit: In particular, I am curious about further information on how it affects the running of Python scripts, and whether it is needed in the code editor window (white background) when I click "Run" for a program I have typed in.]
So far there is no problem with running this. I can click "Run" in the Python window (white background) and install packages from the Python command-type window (black background).
Thanks in advance.

System path is shared by all users, and is appended to user path. If python is not in system path (you did not install it "for all users") then only your user has access to it.

Hi, thanks for the answers and links to a similar question. I am specifically interested in whether it has any impact on running Python scripts from the white-background file window. In there, I enter a file, and can run it directly. Does the PATH affect this? Or is it ONLY when you run Python (i.e. when you type "python" on the command line to start Python, rather than run your specific Python script)? If so, that seems more or less irrelevant, not a real need, right? Most sources seem to say you need this.

This is an off topic question, and SO is not a discussion forum, you should not ask run-on questions in comments.  The questions you are asking are specific to Windows operating system, and apply to any program.  If the .py extension is associated with the installed python interpreter (with it's fully qualified path), then the PATH environment variable will not be used.  PATH is used when you run the python interpreter from the command line.

... But you could equally run start xxxx.py or just xxxx.py  to run the xxxx.py script using the default interpreter (whatever program has been associated wiith .py)

... The difference is both methods start a new console session whereas python xxxx.py (for which you will need PATH runs in the current command shell.  Note if you install from Windows Store, you don't need to set PATH.

@Clifford Thanks very much for the help and advice. I'm sorry if it was off-topic - perhaps someone can tell me why. Eg. is there a specific topic/thread/section just for Python? Before posting, I tried searching for the exact place, but couldn't find anything.

It is not a question of python.  It is a question of how Windows works. What I stated is true of any .exe whether programming related or not.  https://superuser.com/ perhaps.

The PATH variable lets you type python in the command line rather than typing the entire path to the executable. For example:
$ python
>>> 21*2
42

If you only care about GUI-based run buttons (like from the file explorer or an IDE), you might not need to modify PATH. If it's been working already, you're fine - you'll know if you need to set it because everything will break.
That being said, just set it anyways. It shouldn't hurt anything.

Thanks, very helpful - I was a bit nervous that it was being treated as a necessity. It seems optional and easy to fix - if things break immediately, I can worry about it then!

@demneptune adding Python to your PATH is ostensibly optional, but will likely give you more headaches than not. This answer is right, but I'll add to it by saying that PATH (or rather, the value(s) "added" onto it) tell Windows where a given executable is on your machine, and consequently allow you to access that executable (in this case, Python, but it isn't exclusive to that by any means) more easily via the command line.

@JRiggles That's the first and last paragraphs...is there anything specific you'd like to see in the answer?

@Anerdw I just wanted to clarify that this wasn't Python-specific and address OP's remark about it "seem[ing] optional", just in case!
